# How to Generating PDF from a UIWebview

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview

Unable Generating PDF from HTML Template on iOS Device(s). It renders everything else except Image [ Local as well as Server side Image. Even used UIWebview (as my apps min iOS target is 10.3), but still unable to render into a pdf. I have displayed the preview on UIWebview successfully, but when it comes to pdf I only get the Dynamic Text only, nothing else.

```
@objc func downloadPDF(){

    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(webView.viewPrintFormatter(), startingAtPageAt: 0);


    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: webView.frame.size.width, height: webView.frame.size.height) // take the size of the webView
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)
    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

    print(documentsPath)

    pdfData.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/\(self.pdfTitle).pdf", atomically: true)
    AppConfigurations.shared.popAlert(To: "PDF Generate", for: documentsPath, callingView: self)
    self.pdfPath = "\(documentsPath)/\(self.pdfTitle).pdf"

}

@objc func downloadPDF(){

    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(webView.viewPrintFormatter(), startingAtPageAt: 0);


    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: webView.frame.size.width, height: webView.frame.size.height) // take the size of the webView
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)
    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

    print(documentsPath)

    pdfData.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/\(self.pdfTitle).pdf", atomically: true)
    AppConfigurations.shared.popAlert(To: "PDF Generate", for: documentsPath, callingView: self)
    self.pdfPath = "\(documentsPath)/\(self.pdfTitle).pdf"

}
```

My expectation are that I want to generate the PDF with the proper background image and html styling with local as well server side image as well.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but only in iOS 13 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191888/swift-inserting-image-onto-pdf-no-longer-working-on-ios-13